# Internet Explorer 11.0 doesn't recognize document.addEventListener

Tags: internet-explorer, addeventlistener

I have created a very simple HTML file:

```
<script>
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function(event) {
  alert("DOM fully loaded and parsed");
});
</script>
```

When I run this in Internet Explorer 11.0.9600.17937, it complains that document.addEventListener is undefined, and at the same time it shows that the method document.addEventListener exists:

[image: The object does not possess an "addEventListener" property or method]

Is this a passing glitch? In the meantime, how can I work around it?

Comment: Did you try attachEvent ?

Comment: According to Microsoft [attachEvent is no longer supported. Starting with Internet Explorer 11, use addEventListener.](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms536343(v=vs.85).aspx) But it's worse than that: jQuery 2.1.3 throws an error because addEventListener is undefined.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the number in the upper-right corner of the debugger, you're running in IE 5 mode. Make sure you don't have compatibility view on.

Comment: That was it! Now I have to understand how IE got itself into IE 5 mode without me asking it to.